# Как настроить параметры Unity объекта через xml SharedPreference в Android?

Tags: android, c#, unity3d

Добрый день. Помогите понять как реализовать такую вещь, в общем есть задача, при запуске андроид приложения у меня сначала должна запускаться Активити настроек где есть варианты выбора цвета:

```
<ListPreference
    android:entries="@array/pref_color_titles"
    android:entryValues="@array/pref_color_values"
    android:key="@string/pref_select_color_key"
    android:title="Select Color"
    android:summary="Select Color"
/>

<string-array name="pref_color_titles">
    <item>Blue</item>
    <item>Red</item>
  </string-array>
<string-array name="pref_color_values">
    <item>0</item>
    <item>1</item>
  </string-array>
```

далее я выбираю цвет и запускаю собственно саму Unity Активити и весь проект, так вот как мне передать значение из SharedPreference до C# где и должна происходить смена цвета объекта?

```
    void Update () {
      if (pref_color_values == 1){
          Color32 color32 = new Color32 (0, 0, 0, 255);
          GetComponent <Renderer> ().material.color = color32;
      } else {
          Color32 color32 = new Color32 (255, 0, 0, 255);
          GetComponent <Renderer> ().material.color = color32;                        }
    }
```

Comment: А зачем это надо? Что мешает окно настроек прям в юнити сделать?

Comment: @Xumera_hZ это живые обои, так что удобнее использовать стандартный способ настроек

Comment: Держи, может поможет http://suvitruf.ru/2012/09/17/1916/         https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27682977/using-shared-preferences-between-unity-and-native-android-sdk

Comment: @Xumera_hZ это я умею, спасибо

Comment: Надеюсь ты понял, что там 2 ссылки, в одной рассказывают про нативную часть, в другой как передать в юнити, если ты это знаешь, то в чем проблема?

Comment: @Xumera_hZ вот черт, я не заметил, еще раз спасибо, думаю это то что надо

Comment: @Xumera_hZ ты знаешь как работает то что во второй ссылке?